C# Devexpress, update report parameters
I am new using Devexpress report.
I just created a report.
At design time i created parameters.
Now i need to pass parameters by code:
 PreFactura report = new PreFactura();
 
  report.Parameters["CompaniaID"].Value = "01"; // txtcia.Text;
  report.Parameters["OficinaID"].Value = "US.MIA"; // txtOficina.Text;
  report.Parameters["ClienteID"].Value = null;
  report.Parameters["VendedorID"].Value = null;
  report.Parameters["ProductoID"].Value = "P01-00001"; // txtProducto.Text;
  report.Parameters["Desde"].Value = txtFechaDesde.Text;
  report.Parameters["Hasta"].Value = txtFechaHasta.Text;
  report.Parameters["Comando"].Value = null;
  report.RequestParameters = true;
  //  report.DataSource = sqlDataSource;
  // 
//  documentViewer1.DocumentSource = report;
 
//  report.ShowPreview();
 ReportPrintTool printTool = new ReportPrintTool(report);
 printTool.ShowPreview(); //   para seleccionar impresion: .PrintDialog();
 report.CreateDocument();

When the report is displayed it is just appears data with the parameters i created at desing time.
Any helps, please?
Thanks
DevExpress documentation, internet helps,videos.


"When the report is displayed it is just appears data with the parameters i created at desing time. Any helps, please? Thanks"

Can you provide a screen shot of this? I do not understand what you mean.

You can change the parameter visibility.
DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport riport1 = 
DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XtraReport();

DevExpress.XtraReports.Parameters.Parameter param = new 
DevExpress.XtraReports.Parameters.Parameter()
{

    Name = "ParameterName",
    Value = "parameterValue",
    Visible = false //<-  Specifies whether a parameter editor is visible in 
    // the Parameters panel. (true to show a parameter editor; otherwise, false.)
};

riport1.Parameters.Add(param);

In your example:
report.Parameters["ProductoID"].Visible = true;

Documentation with images:
https://docs.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/DevExpress.XtraReports.Parameters.Parameter.Visible
